# change auto image slider to link click slider

Tags: javascript, css

i want change this image slider, as a onclick slider.
this slider is auto slide. i need to slide each image by click a link.

DEMO [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/mzRxB/1/)

```
(function(){
  document.getElementById('slideshow').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].className = "fx";
  window.setInterval(kenBurns, 4000);       
  var images         = document.getElementById('slideshow').getElementsByTagName('img'),
      numberOfImages = images.length,
      i              = 1;
  function kenBurns() {
    if(i==numberOfImages){ i = 0;}
    images[i].className = "fx";
    if(i===0){ images[numberOfImages-2].className = "";}
    if(i===1){ images[numberOfImages-1].className = "";}
    if(i>1){ images[i-2].className = "";}
    i++;
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your javascript as follows:

```
(function(){
  document.getElementById('slideshow').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].className = "fx";

//remove the part that was auto-advancing the images on a timer

  var images         = document.getElementById('slideshow').getElementsByTagName('img'),
      numberOfImages = images.length,
      i              = 1;

//set the ken burns function to go when you click "slideshow"
  slideshow.onclick=function kenBurns() {

    if(i==numberOfImages){ i = 0;}
    images[i].className = "fx";
    if(i===0){ images[numberOfImages-2].className = "";}
    if(i===1){ images[numberOfImages-1].className = "";}
    if(i>1){ images[i-2].className = "";}
    i++;
  }
})();
```

---

#### Edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/enigmadan/mzRxB/4/

Instead of your ken burns effect code, which removes the effect only after an image has passed, you have to remove the effect every time.  This way, no matter what order you click the links, you will be able to see the effect every time.

```
  document.getElementById('slideshow').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].className = "fx";

  var images = document.getElementById('slideshow').getElementsByTagName('img');
  //no longer need i
      numberOfImages = images.length;

                                 //this variable is passed in by the button clicked.  
  window.kenBurns = function (imageNum){

             //using variable to choose image
    images[imageNum].className = "fx";

         //a for loop to remove 'fx' class from all images except the current one.
      for(var i=0;i<numberOfImages;i++){
    if(i===imageNum){ i++}
        images[i].className = "";
    }
  };
```

And then call the function via links that look like this:

```
<a href="javascript:kenBurns(0);">link1</a>
```

Or if you prefer `onclick`:

```
<a onclick="kenBurns(1);" href="javascript:void(0);">link2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, But how to add a link to this. this one slide click on image,

Comment: what do you mean add a link?  Do you want the slides to change when someone clicks the link?  Or do you want a specific link to change to a specific image?

Comment: i want a specific link to change to a specific image

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: If it helped, please make sure to accept it as the answer to this question.